# How to override, prevent or revert Homebrew's changes to compilation flags

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I am debugging a Homebrew formula that is failing due to build variables being clobbered:

```
clang++ called with: -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch i386 -Weverything -O3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ objects/foo.o objects/bar.o -o ../bin/foo_i386
superenv removed:  -arch i386 -Weverything -O3
superenv added:    -pipe -w -Os -march=native -isystem/usr/local/include -isystem/usr/include/libxml2 -isystem/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -L/usr/local/lib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
superenv executed: clang++ -pipe -w -Os -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++ objects/foo.o objects/bar.o -o ../bin/foo_i386 -isystem/usr/local/include -isystem/usr/include/libxml2 -isystem/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -L/usr/local/lib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
```

I would like to preserve the flags that are removed by superenv, removing their replacements (which are added by superenv).

I do want to specify architecture and optimization level, and I don't need to compile in links to XML or OpenGL libraries to a command-line app that does not process XML and does not have a graphical interface or renders a three-dimensional layout.

Here's my formula's `install` block:

```
def install
    ENV.deparallelize
    system 'make all'
    system 'make install'
end
```

Are there any changes to Ruby environment variables I can make in the `install` block of a Homebrew formula to prevent original flags from getting clobbered (as well as keep out unnecessary modifications)?

**What will not work**

This formula will be shared with others. The formula needs to be self-contained, as far as what settings it enables. I do not want to have to reconfigure and recompile the main Homebrew package manager to preserve flags, as this will require the end user to have to do the same customization to their Homebrew installation.

Comment: Don't game the answers, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following modifications helped create a working formula, in terms of addressing the specific issues outlined in my question:

```
class Foo < Formula
    env :std
    ...

    def install
        ENV.O3
        ENV.deparallelize
        ENV.delete('CFLAGS')
        ENV.delete('CXXFLAGS')
        system 'make', 'all'
        system 'make', 'install'
    end
end
```

Adding `env :std` wasn't enough — Homebrew kept adding architecture and other flags and linking options that broke the build process. Deleting the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` changes helped.

Comment: The `ENV.O3` may be superfluous, then.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your formula:

`env :std`

This tells Homebrew to install the formula without superenv by default.  (This can always be overridden by giving the `--env=superenv` option to `brew install`.)

Answer (score 2):

`brew edit formula` will bring up the formula in your editor -- defaults to TextMate. Digging around my install yielded an @Options array in `build_options` which seems to be a set of compile options. Looking at a formula using `brew cat`, for git:

```
require 'formula'

class Git < Formula
  homepage 'http://git-scm.com'
  url 'https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.9.0.tar.gz'
  sha1 'e60667fc16e5a5f1cde46616b0458cc802707743'
  head 'https://github.com/git/git.git'

  bottle do
    sha1 "78bb720052e624b889b7c39e47ec40e463fa13b0" => :mavericks
    sha1 "95b604ef6dff8a8abbc6819b1769c6df6ac45b03" => :mountain_lion
    sha1 "10d46b289e9877f866e953dfc65fde260c80acb8" => :lion
  end

  option 'with-blk-sha1', 'Compile with the block-optimized SHA1 implementation'
  option 'without-completions', 'Disable bash/zsh completions from "contrib" directory'
  option 'with-brewed-openssl', "Build with Homebrew OpenSSL instead of the system version"
  option 'with-brewed-curl', "Use Homebrew's version of cURL library"
  option 'with-persistent-https', 'Build git-remote-persistent-https from "contrib" directory'

  depends_on 'pcre' => :optional
  depends_on 'gettext' => :optional
  depends_on 'openssl' if build.with? 'brewed-openssl'
  depends_on 'curl' if build.with? 'brewed-curl'
  depends_on 'go' => :build if build.with? 'persistent-https'

  resource 'man' do
    url 'http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-manpages-1.9.0.tar.gz'
    sha1 'cff590c92b4d1c8a143c078473140b653cc5d56a'
  end

  resource 'html' do
    url 'http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-htmldocs-1.9.0.tar.gz'
    sha1 '65eb3f411f4699695c7081a7c716cabb9ce23d75'
  end

  def install
    # If these things are installed, tell Git build system to not use them
    ENV['NO_FINK'] = '1'
    ENV['NO_DARWIN_PORTS'] = '1'
    ENV['V'] = '1' # build verbosely
    ENV['NO_R_TO_GCC_LINKER'] = '1' # pass arguments to LD correctly
    ENV['PYTHON_PATH'] = which 'python'
    ENV['PERL_PATH'] = which 'perl'

    if MacOS.version >= :mavericks and MacOS.dev_tools_prefix
      ENV['PERLLIB_EXTRA'] = "#{MacOS.dev_tools_prefix}/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level"
    end

    unless quiet_system ENV['PERL_PATH'], '-e', 'use ExtUtils::MakeMaker'
      ENV['NO_PERL_MAKEMAKER'] = '1'
    end

    ENV['BLK_SHA1'] = '1' if build.with? 'blk-sha1'

    if build.with? 'pcre'
      ENV['USE_LIBPCRE'] = '1'
      ENV['LIBPCREDIR'] = Formula['pcre'].opt_prefix
    end

    ENV['NO_GETTEXT'] = '1' unless build.with? 'gettext'

    system "make", "prefix=#{prefix}",
                   "sysconfdir=#{etc}",
                   "CC=#{ENV.cc}",
                   "CFLAGS=#{ENV.cflags}",
                   "LDFLAGS=#{ENV.ldflags}",
                   "install"

    bin.install Dir["contrib/remote-helpers/git-remote-{hg,bzr}"]

    # Install the OS X keychain credential helper
    cd 'contrib/credential/osxkeychain' do
      system "make", "CC=#{ENV.cc}",
                     "CFLAGS=#{ENV.cflags}",
                     "LDFLAGS=#{ENV.ldflags}"
      bin.install 'git-credential-osxkeychain'
      system "make", "clean"
    end

    # Install git-subtree
    cd 'contrib/subtree' do
      system "make", "CC=#{ENV.cc}",
                     "CFLAGS=#{ENV.cflags}",
                     "LDFLAGS=#{ENV.ldflags}"
      bin.install 'git-subtree'
    end

    if build.with? 'persistent-https'
      cd 'contrib/persistent-https' do
        system "make"
        bin.install 'git-remote-persistent-http',
                    'git-remote-persistent-https',
                    'git-remote-persistent-https--proxy'
      end
    end

    unless build.without? 'completions'
      # install the completion script first because it is inside 'contrib'
      bash_completion.install 'contrib/completion/git-completion.bash'
      bash_completion.install 'contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh'

      zsh_completion.install 'contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh' => '_git'
      cp "#{bash_completion}/git-completion.bash", zsh_completion
    end

    (share+'git-core').install 'contrib'

    # We could build the manpages ourselves, but the build process depends
    # on many other packages, and is somewhat crazy, this way is easier.
    man.install resource('man')
    (share+'doc/git-doc').install resource('html')

    # Make html docs world-readable; check if this is still needed at 1.8.6
    chmod 0644, Dir["#{share}/doc/git-doc/**/*.{html,txt}"]
  end

  def caveats; <<-EOS.undent
    The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
      #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

    The 'contrib' directory has been installed to:
      #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/git-core/contrib
    EOS
  end

  test do
    HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY.cd do
      assert_equal 'bin/brew', `#{bin}/git ls-files -- bin`.strip
    end
  end
end
```

Just changing an option line to it should do what you wish and then a new build.with block. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: What specifically do I change to do to deal with what is being clobbered by Homebrew? Is there a table of options I can lookup to manually set, which will keep my flags from getting whacked?

Comment: They will be overridden when you update your homebrew installation. To avoid this, fork the homebrew project, though you'll need to periodically resync with the other.

Comment: So if I redistribute my formula, then the end user will need to make the same changes to their local Homebrew installation and recompile? I don't think this will work, if so.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but the homebrew people are a friendly lot, so maybe try to pitch it to them on IRC -- irc://irc.freenode.net/homebrew.

Comment: Your answer is not correct or useful for solving the problem as I described it, sorry. But I do appreciate the pointer to the IRC channel. Hopefully they will know more.